# API mode can be implemented with the Plain react application

Tags: jss

Can we implement the API only mode in JSS with a plain react application.? or do we need to have react app created through the JSS.

Also trying to see a sample app or steps to do the API only mode but i don't fidn anything in the documentation https://jss.sitecore.net/

It would be helpful if someone guide on this..

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using API-only mode does not *require* usage of any of the JSS npm packages. In API-only mode, your app is interacting directly with one or more of the Sitecore headless APIs, e.g. Layout Service, GraphQL, etc... For instance, if you want data from Layout Service, you would use the xhr/fetch client of choice and make requests directly to the Layout Service endpoint.

That said, if you are consuming Layout Service data in your React app, you'll likely find a lot of value in using the `@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react` package, specifically the `Placeholder` component and the field helper components, e.g. `Image`, `Text`, etc... All of those components are designed to help render Layout Service data and reduce boilerplate code in your own app.

There are setup steps outlined for API-only mode here: https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/fundamentals/application-modes#api-only-mode

Comment: Thank You Adam.. Hope API only mode doesn't support the Experience Editor by default, Is there a work-around to enable this in API mode.?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Experience Editor requires server-side rendering of your app in order to function properly.

Comment: Thank You Adam for your quick response.. if we use SSR mode then Experience Editor works.? Because i guess that i have seen somewhere that the Experience Editor works only with the integration mode.

Comment: Experience Editor only works in Integrated mode because Experience Editor is a Sitecore application that requires a Sitecore instance. Experience Editor does not work in Headless SSR (proxy) mode.